# SKHeader:Need to edit the header triangle when navigation starts

Tags: java, android, ios, skmaps

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEQXo.png) I have an issue regarding  "SKHeading". When i use (SKMapSettings.SKHeadingMode.ROTATING_MAP) and starts navigation i am getting a triangle on my navigated route which define a header i want to edit that header to smaller one but i am not able to find it in code can you please suggest me how to do that one. So that i can make that header triangle small and play around with it.Below is my code:

```
   SKNavigationSettings navigationSettings = new SKNavigationSettings();
            navigationSettings.setNavigationType(SKNavigationSettings.SKNavigationType.SIMULATION);
            navigationSettings.setPositionerVerticalAlignment(-0.25f);
            navigationSettings.setShowRealGPSPositions(true);
            navigationSettings.setShowStreetNamesPopusOnRoute(true);
            navigationSettings.setDistanceUnit(SKMaps.SKDistanceUnitType.DISTANCE_UNIT_MILES_FEET);
            navigationSettings.getSpeedWarningThresholdInCity();
            SKNavigationManager sknavigation = SKNavigationManager.getInstance();
            sknavigation.setMapView(mapView);
            sknavigation.setNavigationListener(this);
            sknavigation.startNavigation(navigationSettings);
            navigationInProgress = true;
            mapView.centerOnCurrentPosition(17, true, 500);
            mapView.getMapSettings().setHeadingMode(SKMapSettings.SKHeadingMode.ROTATING_MAP);
            startOrientationSensor();
```

This is the line which creates that triangle.
mapView.getMapSettings().setHeadingMode(SKMapSettings.SKHeadingMode.ROTATING_MAP

Please click on image and see the red circled marked.I want to remove that blue color  triangle

Answer (score 0):

To change any textures you must go into the SKMaps.zip file located in your projects assets folder. All the textures used by SKMaps are contained inside this zip file including the ones used for creating the headers. You can change the textures inside the zip file as long as you keep the names the same.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i am not getting the textures for this Heading one. When ever i start navigation the arrow line came again and again.

Comment: I have added the output image can you please have a look on it.

Comment: No that thing is not working. No texture file which relates this in SKMaps.zip