# SKHeading blue color triangle:How to remove/edit SKHeading trianfle header

Tags: java, android, ios, skmaps

[image]
I have an issue regarding  "SKHeading". When i use (SKMapSettings.SKHeadingMode.ROTATING_MAP) and starts navigation i am getting a triangle on my navigated route which define a header i want to edit that header to smaller one but i am not able to find it in code can you please suggest me how to do that one. So that i can make that header triangle small and play around with it.Below is my code:

```
   SKNavigationSettings navigationSettings = new SKNavigationSettings();
            navigationSettings.setNavigationType(SKNavigationSettings.SKNavigationType.SIMULATION);
            navigationSettings.setPositionerVerticalAlignment(-0.25f);
            navigationSettings.setShowRealGPSPositions(true);
            navigationSettings.setShowStreetNamesPopusOnRoute(true);
            navigationSettings.setDistanceUnit(SKMaps.SKDistanceUnitType.DISTANCE_UNIT_MILES_FEET);
            navigationSettings.getSpeedWarningThresholdInCity();
            SKNavigationManager sknavigation = SKNavigationManager.getInstance();
            sknavigation.setMapView(mapView);
            sknavigation.setNavigationListener(this);
            sknavigation.startNavigation(navigationSettings);
            navigationInProgress = true;
            mapView.centerOnCurrentPosition(17, true, 500);
            mapView.getMapSettings().setHeadingMode(SKMapSettings.SKHeadingMode.ROTATING_MAP);
            startOrientationSensor();
```

This is the line which creates that triangle.
mapView.getMapSettings().setHeadingMode(SKMapSettings.SKHeadingMode.ROTATING_MAP

Need to remove/edit this red circle triangle.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SKHeader:Need to edit the header triangle when navigation starts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42675885/skheaderneed-to-edit-the-header-triangle-when-navigation-starts)

Comment: No that thing is not working. No texture file which relates this in SKMaps.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found the solution for this issue if anyone face such kind of issue you just have to comment or make the value of this line

navigationSettings.setShowRealGPSPositions(true);
this line has to look like below:

navigationSettings.setShowRealGPSPositions(false);